# How to sum the values of an measure in MDX?

Tags: sum, mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I am not sure how to put this but, trying to sum the values of an measure using MDX.

My MDX is as follows :

```
select {[CompanyDimension].[Foo], 
        [CompanyDimension].[Bar],
        [CompanyDimension].[CDK]} on columns,

TopCount([${SLRDimension}].Children, 
         10, 
         [Measures].[ProjectCountMeasure]) on rows

from [Foo_Cube]

where ([FAreaDimension].[Admin])
```

For this expression, I am getting following output :

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     | CompanyDimension.NameHierarchy                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SLRDimension        | Foo | Bar     | CDK
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Development         | 1   | 1       | 6
| Testing             |     |         | 3
| Implementation      |     | 1       | 5
| Reports             | 1   |         | 4
| Planning            | 1   |         | 5
| Reporting           |     |         | 1
| Coding              |     |         | 2
| Performance         |     |         | 1
| Designed            |     | 1       |
| Designing           |     |         | 2
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to get the sum of values per row. for example, in 1st row for `Development`, I want its corresponding value to be `7` instead of having 3 values i.e. 1, 1, 6

I am newbie to MDX world so I do not know how to do this. Please help !

I want final values as follows :

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     | CompanyDimension.NameHierarchy                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SLRDimension        | Sum 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Development         | 7
| Testing             | 3
| Implementation      | 6
| Reports             | 5
| Planning            | 6
| Reporting           | 1
| Coding              | 2
| Performance         | 1
| Designed            | 1     
| Designing           | 2
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Pentaho sample data SteelWheelsSales cube as basis, this is similar to what you have now:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Customers].[All Customers]} ON ROWS,
  NON EMPTY {[Markets].[APAC],[Markets].[EMEA]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
```

and this is what you want:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Customers].[All Customers]} ON ROWS,
  NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
WHERE {[Markets].[APAC],[Markets].[EMEA]}
```

notice how I replaced the columns with the measure I want to see, and how I moved the markets to the WHERE clause.